# Show div in a row just below clicked button

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, flexbox

So I have a lot of buttons. I used flex-box.

The tricky part is that I don't know how to place that green block just after the button on a new row. Button with green color means that I clicked on it.

I thought about doing this: we can somehow track the last element in a row(where the button is clicked) and then add a new element with a width of 100% so that it will be on a new line just after the button.

The click will be done using jquery.

I don't have the code for you to share  **BUT** I actually don't need you to write the code, the explanation of how I can do it will be enough.
Thanks.

[image]

Comment: If you're looking to toggle something there's a cool little trick I use that can be done in vanilla Javascript and as a result can be done with any framework surrounding it.

1. define a variable as a Boolean value.

```let toggle = false```

2. Write a function that redefines the variable as the opposite of itself.

```function myFunction() { toggle = !toggle }```

3. write if statements that do certain things based on the boolean value

```if (toggle === true) { do this } else { do this instead }```

hope this helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You somehow need to know in which row does the clicked button belongs.

One way is to get the `.offsetTop` of clicked button. Then, loop through each button until you reach a button with bigger `.offsetTop` value (this means that the button is in a new row). When you find it, insert your block before this button.

```
$('.btn').click((e) => {
    let offsetTop = e.target.offsetTop;
    let buttons = $('.btn');
    for (let i=0; i<buttons.length; i++) {
        if (buttons[i].offsetTop > offsetTop) {
            $('.insert').insertBefore(buttons[i]);
            return;
        }
    }
    //clicked button was in last row
    $('.insert').insertAfter(buttons[buttons.length - 1]);
})
```

Here is a working fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/mxrw1ofL/

Comment: wow, this one is good. But it freezes my computer.

Comment: I think it is just a problem with jsfiddle.

Comment: it works without freezes, thanks

Comment: Please mind some edits in code (in case clicked button is in last row). Check the new fiddle.